# Conversion of Coordinate reference system in Raster objects in R

Tags: r

I am working on NDVI monitoring using Sentinel 2 imagery data.

I have village level boundaries for a region imported as `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` in R. After getting to an NDVI rasterlayer when I try to crop out the area of interest, it says extents do not overlap.

I have found the CRS of my region variable to be `different(longlat)` from my NDVI `layer(utm)`.

```
> crs(ndvi)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=utm +zone=42 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

> crs(region)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

> r <- crop(ndvi,extent(region))
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rgdal::spTranform` on "region" to create an object that has the same crs as "ndvi"

```
library(rgdal)
reg <- spTransform(region, crs(ndvi))
```

and now

```
r <- crop(ndvi, reg)
```

Perhaps followed by

```
m <- mask(r, reg)
```